# tkinter columconfigure and rowconfigure

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to understand something with the grid layout in tkinter. Let's say that I want the column 1 in the row 1 to expand if there is extra space, but the column 1 in the row 2 to not expand how can I can do it?

```
widget.columnconfigure
```

give you control on all columns, it is not possible to specify the row.

Comment: Kindly edit your question as it contains a few mistakes...Also,you question is not clear as to what exactly you are trying to achieve? What have you tried so far? What are the problems you encountered?

Answer (score 7):

You can't do precisely what you want. However, you can get the same visual effect by having the widget in row 1 span two columns where the widget in row 2 spans only one. You can then give weight to the second column, which will affect the widget on row 1 but not on row two.

Here's a simple example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

l1 = tk.Frame(root, background="red", width=100, height=50)
l2 = tk.Frame(root, background="orange", width=100, height=50)
l3 = tk.Frame(root, background="green", width=100, height=50)
l4 = tk.Frame(root, background="blue", width=100, height=50)

root.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
l1.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky="ew")
l2.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky="ew")
l3.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="ew")
l4.grid(row=2, column=3, sticky="ew")

root.mainloop()
```

When this code first starts up, it looks like this where the two columns are identical in size.

[image]

When the window is resized, you can see that the widget on row 1 expands but the widget in row 2 does not.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use two canvases, one for each row. Then change the width and the columnspan of the widget you want to expand. Finally, user columnconfigure.
In the following example, I've created 2 Canvas,2 Frames, 2 buttons. One for each row.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

root.geometry("600x300")
root.resizable(False,False)


canvas_1 = tk.Canvas(master=root,width=600, height=15)
canvas_2 = tk.Canvas(master=root)

canvas_1.pack(expand=True, fill="both")
canvas_2.pack(expand=True, fill="both")


#
frame_1 = tk.Frame(master=root)
frame_1.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

#  ------------------------------------------------------ All in row=0
button_in_column_0 = tk.Button(master=frame_1, text="I'm in Column_1").grid(row=0, column=1) 
button_in_column_1 = tk.Button(master=frame_1, text="I'm in Column_2",width=80).grid(row=0, column=2,columnspan=2)
button_in_column_2 = tk.Button(master=frame_1, text="I'm in Column_3").grid(row=0, column=3)

#  -----Let's say that you want the column 1 in the row 0 to expand if there is extra space
for x in range(2,3):
    frame_1.columnconfigure(x, weight=1)
    frame_1.rowconfigure(x, weight=1)


#  LET CREATE THE SECOND LINE WITH LIST OF BUTTONS

frame_2 = tk.Frame(master=root)
frame_2.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

#  ------------------------------------------------------------ All in row=0
button_1 = tk.Button(master=frame_2, text="I'm in Column_1").grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.NSEW)
button_2 = tk.Button(master=frame_2, text="I'm in Column_2").grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=tk.NSEW)
button_3 = tk.Button(master=frame_2, text="I'm in Column_3").grid(row=0, column=3, sticky=tk.NSEW)


window_1 = canvas_1.create_window(0,1, anchor="nw", window=frame_1)
window_2 = canvas_2.create_window(0,1, anchor="nw", window=frame_2)


root.mainloop()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ru4bq.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

You may be looking for the **columnspan** option.

see http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm

Comment: Since that site is down I'm adding an archive link: you can find the page [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200329152020/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm).