# How To Add Multiple Tables In One Tkinter Frame

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am using a library called tkintertable in python which essentially gives me the capability to efficiently add tables to my Tkinter application. I am trying to setup 6 different tables with 6 charts to go with each table in this frame(my home page essentially) but am relitvely new to tkinter so having some trouble organizing it, currently my code looks like the following:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkintertable import TableCanvas, TableModel

class MainApplication(tk.Tk):
    """Main application class"""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(TickerInput, None)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class, ticker):
        """Destroys current frame and replaces it with a new one."""
        
        if ticker is not None:
           new_frame = frame_class(self, ticker) 
        else:
            new_frame = frame_class(self)

        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()

        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.grid()


class TickerInput(tk.Frame):
    """Ticker input page that allows input of ticker and redirects to main indicator page"""
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, background="#212020")

        # Centers the frame
        self.master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.master.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        ticker_label = tk.Label(self, text="Enter ticker..")
        ticker_label.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2)

        ticker_input = tk.Entry(self, width=35)
        ticker_input.grid(row=0, column=3)
        

        button = tk.Button(self, text="Search", command=lambda: master.switch_frame(Indicator, ticker_input.get()))
        button.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=3)



        
class Indicator(tk.Frame):
    """Indicator page that shows the indicators and whether its a buy or sell"""
    def __init__(self, master, ticker):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.ticker = ticker
        self.master.columnconfigure(0, weight=0)
        self.master.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go Back", command=lambda: master.switch_frame(TickerInput, None))
        button.grid(column=0, row=0)


        ticker_label = tk.Label(self, text=("Current Ticker: " + self.ticker))
        ticker_label.grid(column=1, row=0)

        tableOne = Table(self)
        tableOne.grid(column=0, row=1)
        tableOne.createTable()

        # tableTwo = Table(self)
        # tableTwo.createTable()


class Table(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
    
    def createTable(self):
        data = {'rec1': {'col1': 99.88, 'col2': 108.79, 'label': 'rec1'},
       'rec2': {'col1': 99.88, 'col2': 108.79, 'label': 'rec2'}
       } 

        model = TableModel()
        table = TableCanvas(self.master, model=model, data=data)
        table.show()

        return table




if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MainApplication()
    app.title("Indicator Trading Confirmation Tool")
    app.geometry("1920x1080")
    app.config(background="#121212")
    app.mainloop()
```

and here is the GUI
[image]

Why is my Go Back Button stuck on the table if I have it on a different row and have my weight set to 1 which should seperate them 50% correct? And also what is the best way to organize this both grid/code related to make sure that the GUI has 6 equal tables/charts, 3 on the left and 3 on the right? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, lets go step by step,

1. having replaced your `Table` class with just a colored Frame there is nothing overlapping for me, so this is probably just due to the Layout of the table itself - quick fix for that could be adding some padding
2. the `weight` option is used for distribution of extra space when resizing the window, for more information you can take a look [here](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/grid-config.html), there is also a nice visualization found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21893288/tkinter-columconfigure-and-rowconfigure)

in order to use `weight` for controlling actual used `width` or `height` of your widgets you might want to take a look at the `sticky` option of `grid`
[see](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/grid.html) for a very nice overview you can also check [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20200329152020/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) which is very detailed for both

3. for your general layout you can just go the easy route of combining `weight` and `sticky` options like this:

```
        self.l1 = tk.Frame(self, background="red")
        self.l2 = tk.Frame(self, background="orange")
        self.l3 = tk.Frame(self, background="green")
        self.l4 = tk.Frame(self, background="blue")
        self.l5 = tk.Frame(self, background="brown")
        self.l6 = tk.Frame(self, background="yellow")

        self.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.rowconfigure(1, weight = 1)
        self.rowconfigure(2, weight = 1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight = 1)

        self.l1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.l2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.l3.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.l4.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
        self.l5.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew")
        self.l6.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="nsew")
```

for a 50:50 separation in width and 33:33:33 in height.
If you then later on want to add something like a menubar within your frame you might want to bundle your table frames within another Frame in order to have them resize equally

Comment: Hey thank you for the response! What if i want to add 6 different charts but they are all spaced evenly between each other, I dont want them all touching i want there to be 6 charts throughout the whole screen with even space between them? I removed sticky since i dont believe i want them filling the whole column/row but still having some trouble

Comment: you can just add as much padding as you like, you also have the choice between internal and external, [see](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/grid.html) @LaneFloyd